# Can you/how to get the last Active time on YouTube API V3?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So I was wondering if there was a way to get the last active time of a YouTube channel using YouTube Api V3? Any programing language (Javascript, php, python, eg.). Just asking how to do it if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it will get the last active time but you can use:

## [Activities](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities)

> An `activity` resource contains information about an action that a particular channel, or user, has taken on YouTube. The actions reported in activity feeds include rating a video, sharing a video, marking a video as a favorite, uploading a video, and so forth. Each activity resource identifies the type of `action`, the channel associated with the action, and the resource(s) associated with the action, such as the video that was rated or uploaded.

HTTP request

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities
```

**Note**: Even though an `activity` resource can contain information about actions like a user rating a video or marking a video as a favorite, you need to use other API methods to generate those activity resources. For example, you would use the API's `videos.rate()` method to rate a video and the `playlistItems.insert()` method to mark a video as a favorite.

Comment: Yey, I think I found my answer. If I can just use the last public action the user did, and use it as the time the user was last active, then that would suit my needs.